# how to perform segue from root view controller to the last view controller in the navigation stack in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

I have 3 View controllers that embedded in the navigation controller stack. RedVC, BlueVC and YellowVC. In the each view controllers there are button that will trigger the segue

from RedVC, I want to navigate either to BlueVC or to YellowVC. All the segue from RedVC to BlueVC and to YellowVC are connected using push show segue, not present modally.

There is no problem if the route is like this :
RedVC -> BlueVC -> YellowVC

but if I push show segue from redVC directly to YellowVC, the back button in the YellowVC will direct me back to RedVC

[image]

I want, if I segue from RedVC to YellowVC, I want the back button in the YellowVC will direct me to BlueVC, not RedVC.

how to achieve this?

Comment: If you are directly calling segue 3 from segue 1, you are overlooking the segue 2. One possible solution can be maintaining the status of the clicked segue whether it is 2 or 3 and customize the back button functionality of ViewController 3. You will be initializing ViewController 2 on the back button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are moving from RedVC to YellowVC so you could not come back to BlueVC after tapping back of yellowVC.**

But this can be achieve in a way like:

Keep a flag variable called : `shouldShowYellowDirectly` in BlueVC and set its value `true` and from RedVC in prepareForSegueMethod.

In BlueVC do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   if shouldShowYellowDirectly{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showYellow", sender: self)
   }
}
```

**It will show BlueVC for fraction of second.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are to move from **RedVC** to **YellowVC** directly (skipping **BlueVC**), it will rule out the possibility of **BlueVC** getting initialised. Thereby, when you'll perform back navigation from **YellowVC**, you have to forcefully initialise **BlueVC** for achieving what you want.
Though this is not advisable as it won't follow the default VC life cycle. But if you are to do so, you need to explicitly take care of the behaviour. As an example - persisting data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add another *non-animated* segue between red and blue.

Uncheck the "Animates" checkbox in the property inspector.

[image]

To go to yellow, perform this segue first and pass a `true` flag that indicates whether we are going to yellow to blue. In blue, handle this flag. If the flag is true, perform the animated segue to yellow. If we are just going to blue, the animated segue to blue will be performed and the flag will be `false`.

Another solution is to do this programmatically without segues. Give your blue and yellow VCs some identifiers:

[image]

To go to yellow, instantiate your blue and yellow VCs:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.main!
let blue = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Blue")
let yellow = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Yellow")
```

And then push blue unanimated, and then yellow animated:

```
    navigationController?.pushViewController(blue, animated: true)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(yellow, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert blueVC in prepareForSegue method. You can follow below code

```
override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) {
         super.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: sender);

         if identifier == "xyz" {
            var navArray : [AnyObject]! = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
            navArray.insert(blueVC, atIndex: navStackArray.count - 2)
            self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(navArray, animated:false)
         }
     }
```

In above, blueVC you need to crate that object and put there. Hope this help!